# Desktop application displays "Chrome Legacy window" - can't automate

Tags: ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to automate one windows application using coded ui, application is built on ext.js, when i tried to inspect elements using UIspy  the entire window is considered as one element   as "Chrome Legacy Window", so cant able to access the individual elements

I did lot of research on google, found similar questions on other sites where people struggled with same problem but questions remains unanswered

Please help to find a solution

Thanks in advance
Abhijth

Comment: What did you find from the many web pages about this exact topic? Please explain what you have tried and why those other web pages were unhelpful. Is your question a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947203/chrome-legacy-window-when-launching-chrome-with-runas ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried searching same in google, found similar question on git, but question remains unanswered, this question is not duplicate of above link

Comment: Ok, please [edit] the question to explain what you have tried and why those other web pages were not helpful. Also to explain why your question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Hi I have edited the question

Comment: Hi, Any answers for my query ?

Comment: Does your automation tool of choice allow you to use MS UI Automation "UIAObject" interfaces within applications?